# Crystal Reports: Is there a way to get effectively a subreport within a subreport?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2005, crystal-reports, subreport

**UPDATE:** I asked a more general question here:  [Can I do two levels of linking in Crystal Reports?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2166963/can-i-do-two-levels-of-linking-in-crystal-reports)

I'm using Crystal Reports within VB.NET and Visual Studio 2005.

I have a report with several subreports.  I'm setting List(Of MainStuff) as the data sources for the main report.  I'm setting List(Of SubreportStuff) as the data source for the subreport.  Each SubreportStuff has a key which links back to a particular MainStuff, so the report groups each MainStuff item with its related SubreportStuff items.  (Or, at the DB level, SubreportStuff items have a foreign key, which is the primary key in MainStuff.)

Below shows the Load function for the dialog, which contains a CrystalReportsViewer.  In the Crystal Reports report editor (within VS 2005) I set the subreport link to pull only the related items into that part of the report.

```
Imports System.Windows.Forms

    Public Class dlgMyReport
        Private rpt As New MyReport
        Public theMainList As New List(Of MainStuff)
        Dim theSubreportList As New List(Of SubreportStuff)

        Private Sub dlgMyReport_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
            rpt.SetDataSource(theMainList)

            If theSubreportStuff.Count > 0 Then
                rpt.Subreports.Item("subReport").SetDataSource(theSubreportList)
            End If

            Me.StuffViewer.ReportSource = rpt
        End Sub

        ... ' other subs and functions

    End Class
```

This works fine.

Now, though, what I'm needing to do is in essence the same thing, but pull items based on the keys in the *subreport* items.  This would mean having a subreport within a subreport.  However, it doesn't appear that I can do this (the option for inserting a subreport is grayed out when I try to insert in something that is already a subreport).

Is there a way that I can accomplish this?  (Can I carry the subreport relationship down another level in some way?)

Thanks as always!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Subreports within subreports are not possible within Crystal Reports.

Comment: Thanks for confirming my suspicions.  Is there a way to include a list of items within a subreport where this list of items has the subreport item as a primary key?

Comment: I generalized my question here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2166963/can-i-do-two-levels-of-linking-in-crystal-reports

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question.  Do you mean, 'Is there a way to link the main report to the subreport, where the data in the subreport is based on a data value in the main report?'?  If so, the answer is 'Yes.'.

In any case, you can achieve your desired result without using a sub-report.  Start by adding the three tables to your report and link them as desired. Next, insert a group for each: department_name, division_name, and  group_name.  Finally, profit.