# Can I do two levels of linking in Crystal Reports?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2005, crystal-reports, subreport

Let's say I have three lists:  Departments, Divisions, and Groups.  A Department is made up of Divisions, which in turn is made up of Groups.

The Divisions have the Department ID as a foreign key.  The Groups have the Division ID as a foreign key.

I'd like to produce a report that looks like this:

```
Department 1
    Division 1A
        Group 1A-i
        Group 1A-ii
        Group 1A-iii
    Division 1B
        Group 1B-i
        Group 1B-ii
        Group 1B-iii
    Division 1C
        Group 1C-i
        Group 1C-ii
        Group 1C-iii
Department 2
    Division 2A
        Group 2A-i
        Group 2A-ii
        Group 2A-iii
    Division 2B
        Group 2B-i
        Group 2B-ii
        Group 2B-iii
    Division 2C
        Group 2C-i
        Group 2C-ii
        Group 2C-iii
Department 3
    Division 3A
        Group 3A-i
        Group 3A-ii
        Group 3A-iii
    Division 3B
        Group 3B-i
        Group 3B-ii
        Group 3B-iii
    Division 3C
        Group 3C-i
        Group 3C-ii
        Group 3C-iii
```

[I know how to use a subreport](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2166906/crystal-reports-is-there-a-way-to-get-effectively-a-subreport-within-a-subrepor) in Crystal Reports (VB.NET and Visual Studio 2005) to get me to the Division level:

```
Department 1
    Division 1A
    Division 1B
    Division 1C
Department 2
    Division 2A
    Division 2B
    Division 2C
Department 3
    Division 3A
    Division 3B
    Division 3C
```

But since [I can't include a subreport within a subreport](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2166906/crystal-reports-is-there-a-way-to-get-effectively-a-subreport-within-a-subrepor), I'll need to go about it some other way.  Is there a way to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to use groups? You can just link the tables by their foreign keys and create a group for Department, another one for Division and put the groups in the details.

Here is a [tutorial](http://www.crystalreportsbook.com/Crystal_Reports_XI.asp?Page=3_2)